# How can I create a constant keras tensor of variable length?

Tags: keras

I am trying to create a tensor of zeros of variable length for inputs using keras backend but unable to define the shape of the same. The sample code is shown below:

```
from keras import backend as K

def func():
  const = K.constant(0, dtype='float', shape=[?,1])
  return const
```

Of course such a syntax would not work. Can somebody tell me how I can rectify this?